# Angular Materials Flex-box not being displayed properly on iOS Safari

Tags: css, flexbox, angular-material

I am trying to add a feature which displays 4 material-design cards side-by-side. It works perfectly fine on all the other browsers except safari/ios. The markup is as follows.

```
     <div layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-xs="column" layout-align="space-around start" layout-align-sm="center stretch" layout-align-xs="center stretch" >

    <div flex="grow" flex-sm="grow" flex-xs="grow" layout="row" layout-xs="row" layout-align="space-around start" layout-align-xs="center stretch">
        <md-card flex="grow" layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex-gt-sm="50"  class="selling-points-card"  >
            <div  class="selling-points-picture" >
                <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
            <span  class="selling-points-text">Free Service Included</span>        
            </div>
        </md-card>

        <md-card flex="grow" layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex-gt-sm="50"  class="selling-points-card"  >
            <div  class="selling-points-picture" >
                <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
            <span  class="selling-points-text">30 Day Money back guarentee</span>        
            </div>
        </md-card>
    </div>

    <div flex="grow" flex-sm="grow" flex-xs="grow" layout="row" layout-xs="row" layout-align="space-around start" layout-align-xs="center stretch">
        <md-card flex="grow" layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex-gt-sm="50"  class="selling-points-card"  >
            <div  class="selling-points-picture" >
                <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
            <span  class="selling-points-text">90 Day Warranty</span>        
            </div>
        </md-card>
        <md-card flex="grow" layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex-gt-sm="50"  class="selling-points-card"  >
            <div  class="selling-points-picture" >
                <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
            <span  class="selling-points-text">FreedomPop Certified</span>        
            </div>
        </md-card>
    </div>

    </div>
**css rules**
.selling-points-card{
position:relative; 
display:inline-block;
box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
.selling-points-picture {
    display:inline-block; 
    padding:5px;
};
.selling-points-text{
    position:absolute; 
    top:40%; left:30%; 
    font-weight:500; 
    font-size:12px; 
    letter-spacing: 0.020em;
};
```

}

This is how it looks like on most browsers.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HCzD.png

However on the iPhone simulator those 4 cards get cut off by search results.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWvPb.png

Does anyone know what I could be missing? 
And another question...is there a right way to format the span text so that it is centered in the middle of its parent card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your main problem, have you tried using other values for the `flex`property ?

And to center the text in the parent element, use the `layout="row"`and `layout-align="center center"` properties of Angular Material. 
(You may have to use block elements in order to make it work)

Comment: Thanks! I fixed my first problem by cleaning up the markup, some attributes werent needed.  center-center works on the text but with how I have it structured the picture is centered as well. I would like the picture to stay centered at the start, but space-between/around don't work too well. This is how it looks like right now.
https://i.imgur.com/s7tYE2Q.png

Comment: This fixed a weird issue I had on iOS for img elements. I had a flex="100" and after removing it everything started to work.